# Php array_walk with anonymous function for filtering out results

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function, array-walk

I have a big set of time records for a project and I want to filter out all but those posted by a single employee.

```
array_walk($timeRecords, function($timeRecord, $index) use ($employee) {
    if ($timeRecord->employeeId != $employee->id) {
        unset($timeRecords[$index]);
    }
});
```

You can see what I'm trying to do. How do you go about doing this with anon functions and closures? Obviously $timeRecords is not defined inside the anonymous function. Thanks.

Comment: you might want to have a look at `array_filter()` which is slightly more suited to the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calimero pointed out that's the wrong tool for the job. The desired effect can be achieved using array_filter. Array_walk appears to be designed for modifying individual array items by reference.

This is how to achieve what I was wanting.

```
$timeRecords = array_filter($timeRecords, function($timeRecord) use ($employee) {
    if ($timeRecord->EmployeeId == $employee->EmployeeId) {
        return $timeRecord;
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look again at the docs of `array_filter()`, you just need to return true/false if you want to keep the element or not

Comment: Ah I missed that. It's right there in the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Thanks.